# Code snippet manager for Ubuntu?

Tags: development, source-code, kubuntu

I'm looking for a good code snippet manager, with syntax highlighting and search capabilities. Another important feature is the capability of changing the code area background color. I have tested some Adobe Air apps that had white background everywhere, which hurts my eyes.

I'm using KDE btw. I use Kate for coding, but I don't like it's snippet plugin.

Comment: I don't really like snippet plugins because the encourage copy-and-paste style coding. What you should be trying to do is to write good javascript libraries of find some that do it for you so that you do not need these snippets lying around. That would be my suggestion.

Comment: I agree with you, to a certain point. The problem is that I need to constantly access Firefox's API with the same methods. So is not a matter of writing a library to avoid copy and paste.

Comment: @Robert, i think that's a little BS. Just because I don't want to write `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.js"></script>` or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` over and over again rather than just a simple key combo like `ctrl+alt+shift+j` or whatever doesn't make us bad developers...

Comment: @Oscar Your opinion is fine, if you want to do that and you like it then that is fine. Notice that I did not say that it makes you a bad developer but rather that it encourages a style that I do not think is good; doing it though does not make you a bad developer. I offered an opinion with no facts which means that anybody can take it or leave it and that your comment is equally valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), which has a really nice snippet manager, with support for variables and drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 6):

If you're working in python, [Acire](http://aciresnippets.wordpress.com/) is a good choice.

[image: acire]

First, you need to install the Python Snippets library

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:python-snippets-drivers/python-snippets-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-snippets
```

Then you can install Acire itself:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:acire-team/acire-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acire
```

Comment: I work mainly with XUL and Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

instead of kate i recommend you Gvim and the [SnipMate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), it's highly customizable, and really easy to use. Greetings

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I really like kate and don't like vim.

Answer (score 2):

You should try Code Barrel.  It is cloud based so you can get your snippets anywhere.  Oh, and it's free.

Comment: Thanks. It looks awesome. I have tried it is what I'm looking for. The problem is that it is kind of slow and you can only store 25 snippets in the free plan. I'm definitely not willing to pay $9.95 a month to store snippets. I think this is more useful for companies with many developers.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I thought i'd add:
http://code.google.com/p/snippely/

I *hate* AIR apps, but this one was an exception. It's well designed and works well.

Comment: Google Code has shut down. Has this project been moved elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for a good snippet manager tool, may I recommend QSnipps. It's cross-platform, has syntax highlighting, supports database share across all your computers.. etc.

Give it a try at: http://www.qsnipps.com/

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, try [gistboxapp](http://www.gistboxapp.com/), this is an extension for Chrome. You can use this in any platform. It is very light.

Answer (score 0):

Use a post-it application, like TomBoy or [GNote](https://live.gnome.org/Gnote/).
It's light and nice and stays in the panel at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Snip2Code - http://www.snip2code.com.

It allows the user to collect, organize and share code snippets, from the web site as well as directly within the preferred IDE (Visual Studio, Eclipse, IntelliJ, Notepad++) or through the native apps for Windows8 and Mac OS X.

Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Well Here are Some Really good , Colur full and light softwares:
bluefish
gedit(comes with default
geany
emacs
qt creator
and many more

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Molimentum Quick](https://molimentum.com) (disclaimer: I'm the founder). It's available for Ubuntu. You can insert code snippets with ease with some shortcuts (check out the "smart insert" feature in docs). You can then click a shortcut, search, and it's copied to the clipboard. It supports syntax highlighting and because of the versatile design, it works in every editor. It also supports a dark theme.