# Snippet code manager like Snippets?

Tags: software-recommendation, development, source-code, macosx, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code snippet manager for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6035/code-snippet-manager-for-ubuntu)

I'm looking some snippets code manager on Ubuntu like Snippets (for the MAC) with syntax highlighting (html, css, php).  Thanks for help.

Comment: Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/6035/code-snippet-manager-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Snippets, but gedit has code highlighting and is extendible using plugins. You can also add code pieces to it for your own use.

Comment: Thanks. I know gedit, but I want to use my code globally and not only in gedit.